# ionicPlatform.ready() function to use service factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app.js I have this method:

```
  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        gvi.Notifications.registerForPush(MessagesService.onNotificationResponse);

     });
  })
```

And a factory:

```
  .factory('MessagesService', function($scope, $q) {

var messages = [];

    return {

  onNotificationResponse: function(sender, message, msgId, msgType, msgUrl) {
        console.log("myApp.onNotificationResponse:" + message + " msgUrl:" + msgUrl);

        $scope.messages.push({
          sender: sender,
          message: message,
          msgId: msgId,
          msgType: msgType,
          msgUrl: msgUrl
        });

      MessagesService.save($scope.messages);

    },
  }
 })
```

When I open the app, I get this error:

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: MessagesService is not defined
```

How do I use the MessagesService factory in the ionicPlatform.ready function?

EDIT:

I have fixed the MessagesService error, now how do I use $scope in the factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not passed the `MessageService` dependency in run

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,MessagesService) {
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        gvi.Notifications.registerForPush(MessagesService.onNotificationResponse);

     });
  })
```

Update: Based on your requirement you need to refactor your service since service cannot refer to scope.
You service should expose the message array to scope, rather than using the one defined on scope.

```
 .factory('MessagesService', function($scope, $q) {

var messages = [];

    return {

  onNotificationResponse: function(sender, message, msgId, msgType, msgUrl) {
        console.log("myApp.onNotificationResponse:" + message + " msgUrl:" + msgUrl);

        messages.push({
          sender: sender,
          message: message,
          msgId: msgId,
          msgType: msgType,
          msgUrl: msgUrl
        });

      MessagesService.save(messages);

    },
    messages:messages
  }
 })
```

Now you can reference this messages collection in any controller using `MessageService.messages` property.

Comment: Added that, then I get this: Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- MessagesService

Comment: You are not allowed to pass $scope as dependency to your service. Scopes exist in context of html. You need to pass the messages as input parameter to the method that needs to save the message.

Comment: how do I call my controller function from inside the MessagesService onNotificationResponse function?

Comment: You reference service from your controller not the other way around. you Service does not hold reference to the controller or directly call controller. Can you explain more about your scenario?

Comment: Sure. when the app starts up it calls registerForPush with a callback function (which is the onNotificationResponse one). The registerForPush function calls my server to check for messages for the app. When it finds a message it calls the callback function. The callback function must then add the message to scope so that it can be viewed on the messages.html page.